# Using the "master file" with emacs and Sweave

Tags: include, emacs, sweave

One of the things I love about emacs is being able to specify a master file, then compile an included `.tex` file - I just use `C-c C-b`

For sweave documents, I have the following layout:

- `master.Rnw`

  - `\SweaveInput{chapter1}`
  - `\SweaveInput{chapter2}`
  - `\SweaveInput{chapter3}`

I would like to use the same idea as `C-c C-b` to only sweave/latex `chapter1`. Is this possible in emacs?

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert on Sweave, but it seems to be integrated in the [ESS](http://ess.r-project.org/) package with an Rnw and Snw mode where you can have it run Sweave or R on the buffer code directly. So that might be what you want if it's just to preview the sweave file result.

I also found details on integrating ESS more tightly with AUCTeX [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/auctex@gnu.org/msg02181.html). It's not tested, but C-c C-c is mapped to run the command on the master file, so it might work for you.

While this is not a complete answer, I hope it helps. I put it in WIKI mode so you can add more details if you find anything more.

Comment: @Mortimer no you changed it the wrong way!

Comment: I Fixed it now...

Comment: On SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2940756/ess-auctex-sweave-integration

Answer (score 0):

I doubt this sort of thing is possible, because running tex just on chapter 1 won't work, since it will need the common preamble which is presumably in the master document. And if you run tex on the master, then it doesn't know to only do the first chapter.

One way to do what you want is to use `\includeonly` to tell the compiler which files to include. (I expect the `\SweaveInput` has a similar command...) [See here for some details](http://web.science.mq.edu.au/~rdale/resources/writingnotes/latexstruct.html)

If the problem is you want emacs to treat `.Rnw` files like `.tex` files, try adding this to your .emacs:

```
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rnw~?$" . latex-mode))
```

Comment: In emacs `C+c C+b` copies the preamble and the "included file" into a temporary file called _region.tex. It then latexs that file. Of course, chapter numbers, etc, are off. But it's very handy for quick checks.

Comment: @csgillespie That's interesting. I've always just compiled with `C-c C-c`. Why doesn't exactly the same thing work with sweave documents? I'd have thought the process would be identical...

Comment: To sweave a document you use the command `M-n s` and it doesn't (seem) to have any idea about the concept of a master file. I tried to hack my `.emacs`, but things quickly got messy. For example, auctex expects `.tex` file extensions. At this point, I thought there must be a better way.

Comment: @csgillespie `C-c C-b` type `Other` and then try typing `Sweave` at the next prompt. Does this work?

Comment: No. I think it something to do with the file extensions (they're .Rnw not .tex).